# Colocar dos colores al texto estilo degrade en un elevated button en flutter

Tags: flutter

Deseo colocar dos colores al texto estilo degrade en un elevated button en flutter, ¿cómo debería hacer?

El código sería:

```dart
 Widget _buildLoginBtn() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.8),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)))),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserScreen()),
          );
        },
        child: Text(
          'INICIAR SESION',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
            letterSpacing: 2.5,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Nexa',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

La idea es que INICIAR esté en color rojo y SESION en negro, por ejemplo.

Probé agregar dos text pero no es válido dentro del button.

Quisiera crear un tema o alguna función degrade y poder "partirlo".

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con degrade? ¿Que haya un degradado del color en el texto de rojo a negro? ¿Que cada letra tenga un color diferente de rojo a negro? ¿O que iniciar sea todo rojo y sesión todo negro? Intenta especificar bien qué quieres, porque tipo degrade, puede significar mil cosas.

Comment: Por supuesto que puedes agregar dos textos dentro de un botón. Simplemente tienes que hacer que el hijo del botón sea un Row y que el Row, tenga como hijos a los textos.

Comment: Perdon por expresarme mal, INICIAR tendria que tener un color, y SESION otro color

Comment: A ver si alguna de las respuestas que hay aquí te sirven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686868/gradient-text-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un `shader` para adaptar la propiedad `foreground` a tu gusto, en tal caso tu necitas realizar un degradado del texto. Primero tienes que inicializar el `shader` y asignarle el `LinearGradient`:

```
Shader gradient =
  const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.black])
      .createShader(const Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 200.02, 70.0));
```

luego en el `TextStyle` a la propiedad `foreground` le asignas el `Shader` de  la siguiente manera:

```
Text(
      'INICIAR SESION',
      style: TextStyle(
        //color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
        foreground: Paint()..shader = gradient)
        letterSpacing: 2.5,
        fontSize: 20.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: 'Nexa',
      ),
    ),
```

Adicional a esto el `LinearGradient` tiene la propiedad de `stops` que te permitira poner fracciones que define desde donde hasta(0.5, 1) para que acoples mejor los colores que has asignado:

```
stops: [0.5, 1.0]
```

Y con eso ya le estarías dando un efecto degradado a tu texto.

Comment: Realice esto, pero me toma solo el ultimo color del gradient, la idea es que INICIAR tenga un tono rojo, y SESION este en negro

Comment: si hiciste un hot reload?

Comment: Sisi, cerré todo y lo volví a levantar, solo toma el Negro no le da bola al rojo

Comment: es raro, con eso debería funcionarte...

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar eso deberias agregar un row en tu child y dentro dos textos, y acada texto su respectivo color

child: Row(
Text(
'INICIAR',
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.Red,
letterSpacing: 2.5,
fontSize: 20.0,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontFamily: 'Nexa',
),
),
Text(
'Sesion',
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black,
letterSpacing: 2.5,
fontSize: 20.0,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontFamily: 'Nexa',
),
),
)

Comment: Para dar formato a tu código, agrega triples acentos graves (_backticks_, `) una línea antes y una después del mismo. Por cierto, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.